# Angular conditionally use directive attr inside directive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with using directive conditionally inside another directive,
so let's say I have one directive 'myGrid' and in it's template I have something like this:

```
<table my-grid-resizable>...</table>
```

and I want to use myGridResizable directive only if I use myGrid directive like this:

```
<my-grid resizable="true" />
```

But I don't want to use ng-if inside template of myGrid directive.

I tried this:

```
 if (scope.resizable) {
            angular.element(element).find('table').attr('my-grid-resizable', ''); }
```

But it's not working, attribute is added but directive is not working, recompiling directive is't helping as well.

Thanks for help in solving this

Answer (score 0):

You're just setting the attribute, however, this does not mean that the DOM will be digested on it's own. The reason your DOM doesn't update is because you're not updating any model or binding. You're just modifying the DOM.

So you're gonna have to manually compile your element like,

First, inject `$compile` in your directive or controller (whichever is applicable)

Then do:

```
if (scope.resizable) {
    angular.element(element).find('table').attr('draco-grid-dynamic-table', '');
    var html = angular.element(element).find('table').html();
    var compiledHtml = $compile(html)(scope);
    angular.element(element).find('table').html(compiledHtml);
}
```

This way, however works, but is not an angular way and is highly discouraged.
I do not understand why you don't want to use `ng-if` structure. It is the angular way of doing things.

Comment: And I don't want to use ng-if to not duplicate code

Comment: @Michal Yeah, you don't want to duplicate code..There is one way to avoid duplicating a lot of code though. You could wrap what ever is supposed to go inside `ng-if` into a separate template file and `ng-include` it inside the `ng-if`s